# Как смержить перевод приложения на Android

Tags: android, xml, перевод

Никак не найду как делается объединение строк для переводов в Android.

Есть набор values и есть его перевод values-ru как добавить не достающие строки в values-ru из values ? Ведь strings.xml обычный xml, искал как объединить xml под GNU/Linux ничего не нашёл, только платный утилиты с одной функцией объединения под windows.

Если есть какая-то утилита, то нужна под GNU/Linux, так и не понял можно ли это сделать с помощью xmlutils.

или подскажите эта функция есть только у Android Studio?

В общем нужны функции утилит gettext (msgmerge), только для Android переводов, думал это легко найти и Google нормально об этом рассказывает, но нет. ничего подобного я не нашёл.

Пример, того о чём речь:

Есть values/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello!</string>
    <string name="world">World</string>
</resources>
```

И есть values-ru/strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Привет!</string>
</resources>
```

как объединить эти 2 файла, чтобы на выходе получить

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Привет!</string>
    <string name="world">World</string>
</resources>
```

Если некто не слышал об "Официальном" выходе из ситуации, то да, придётся просто свой парсинг написать. Просто странно, что стандартный механизм для перевода в Android не имеет таких нужных и простых функций, как: объединения и удаления уже отсутствующих строк, в файлах перводов

Comment: *Если есть какая то утилита, то нужна под GNU/Linux* — приведите, пожалуйста, пример того, что у вас есть, и того, что хотите получить в результате.

Comment: _Если есть какая-то утилита_ - это уже _не по теме_. Утилиты - это к Google и на другие сайты. По поводу объединения - дело само по себе не хитрое, так что если ничего не найдёте, то можно просто написать скрипт, который будет делать это.

Comment: Добавил пример. Дело ведь в том, что таких фалов переводов много и вручную строчки добавлять не вариант.

Comment: @Regent , Это не Вам был ответ. Обновил вопрос. Да, про скрипт понятно. просто залез в Android проект, никогда прежде не лазея и не могу найти и не у кого спросить про то, почему такого инструментария нету.

Comment: увы, ничего подходящего не встречал. тут нужен [*xslt*-файл](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), в котором описаны необходимые трансформации, а уж инструментов для «выполнения» *xslt* — в природе более чем достаточно.

Comment: можете просто не добавлять непереведенный строки в локализованный файл. Тогда они (отсутствующие строки) будут браться из values/strings

Comment: @metalurgus , не, смысл как раз в том, чтобы после, перевести новые строки в файлах переводов.

Comment: т.е., задача несколько иная: получить те строки из первого файла, перевод которых не встречается во втором?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , это как раз и есть основная задача, которая и описана. но перевод тут не причём, нужно ориентироваться на атрибут "name" если такого нет во втором файле, то вставить из первого. А если есть во втором, а в первом нету то удалить из второго. (первый - values, втрой - values-ru)

Comment: @X-NicON, если многострочные тэги (`<string` на одной строке,  а `</string` — на другой) не встречаются в файлах, то получение списка «новых» строк решается не очень сложным «однострочником» из grep+sort+sed+diff. если встречаются — «однострочником», думаю, уже не обойтись. удаление же из второго — та же самая задача, только файлы меняются местами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Короче, ответа так и не услышал. Ближе и понятнее всего, работа была через php, так что наваял объединение андроид xml ресурсов. очень грубо и прямолинейно, только для типа "String". в общем то, что нужно было конкретно мне.

```
function mergeAndrLangXml($from, $to){
    $xml_from = new DOMDocument();
    $xml_from->load($from);
    $xml_to = new DOMDocument();
    $xml_to->load($to);
    $xml_to->formatOutput =true;
    $xpath_from = new DOMXpath($xml_from);
    $xpath_to = new DOMXpath($xml_to);

    //Удаляем отсутствующие в from из to
    foreach( $xml_to->getElementsByTagName('string') as $v ){
        $find = $xpath_from->query('string[@name="'.$v->getAttribute("name").'"]');

        if($find->length == 0){
            $v->parentNode->removeChild($v);
        }
    }

    // Добавляем новые из from в to
    foreach( $xml_from->getElementsByTagName('string') as $v ){
      if($v->getAttribute('translatable') != 'false'){
        $find = $xpath_to->query('string[@name="'.$v->getAttribute("name").'"]');
        if($find->length == 0){
            $newElem = $xml_to->createElement('string',$v->textContent);
            $newElem->setAttribute('name',$v->getAttribute('name'));
            $xml_to->getElementsByTagName('resources')->item(0)->appendChild($newElem);
        }
      }
    }

    //марафет
    $file = $xml_to->saveXML($xml_to, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
    $file = str_replace("ng><","ng>\n<", $file);
    $file = str_replace("\n<string","\n    <string", $file);
    $file = str_replace("\n    \n","\n", $file);

    file_put_contents($to,$file);
}
```